# Search from the string array and ignore that exact matched string

Tags: c#, linq

how can I ignore the exact matched from the string array with linq query

here is my code whats wrong with it

```
public string GetItems(string SearchText, Int64 userID, Int64 orgID, Int64 locationID, string[] selectedProductName)
{
    List<Product> searchList = new List<Product>();
    string jsonText = "";
    try
    {            
            searchList = dbContext.usp_ang_GetProductList_(orgID, SearchText, locationID, 0).ToList();
            var abc = searchList.Where(a => a.Name.Any(a.Name != selectedProductName).ToList();
            jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(abc);            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return jsonText;
}
```

Comment: Question is unclear. What do you mean by "exact match"?

Comment: @GiladGreen : Suppose that string array selectedProductName has any name like "Orange or "Apple" then it ignore those string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the `.Any` is incorrect:

1. In your current use you are checking if `any` of the `char`s that
   construct `a.name` match some predicate.
2. `.Any(a.Name != selectedProductName)` - you need to form a properly formatted lambda expression

You want to check if `any` of the values of the `selectedProductName` array is equals to the `a.Name`.

```
var abc = searchList.Where(a => !selectedProductName.Any(name => name == a.Name)).ToList();
```

Because `selectedProductName` is a `string[]` it is cleaner just to use `.Contains`:

```
var abc = searchList.Where(a => !selectedProductName.Contains(a.Name)).ToList();
```

---

Also it is a shame to bring all that data from the database just to filter it the row after. If you remove the `ToList()` the filtering will happen in the database:

```
var abc = dbContext.usp_ang_GetProductList_(orgID, SearchText, locationID, 0)
                   .Where(a => !selectedProductName.Contains(a.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: selectedProductName is an array of string

Comment: @Adrian Iftode - Thank for fixing the typo :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if name not present in the `selectedProductName` list, for this you can use `Contains` clause

```
var abc = searchList.Where(a => !selectedProductName.Contains(a => a.Name )).ToList();
```

and for better performance you can do all the things in one statement

```
var abc = dbContext.usp_ang_GetProductList_(orgID, SearchText, locationID, 0)
                  .Where(a => !selectedProductName.Contains(a.Name)).ToList();
```